# Calling protected methods of objects created in php_pthread thread context

Tags: php, multithreading, scope, pthreads

I'm experimenting with [php_pthreads](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php) functionality and am facing a strange problem with one of my library classes.

Parent of that class has a public constructor calling one of its own protected methods. The class I need extends that protected method, so when a constructor is called it would invoke that redefined method instead. Simplified code:

```
class FoobarParent {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->_init();
    }

    protected function _init() {
        // do something
    }
}

class Foobar extends FoobarParent {
    protected function _init() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Now when I try using an instance of that class in the thread, I get `Call to protected method Foobar::_init() from context 'FoobarParent'`:

```
class T extends Thread {
    public function run() {
        $foo = new Foobar();
    }
}
```

Note that the object is created in thread context and not passed from the outside - this was the first thing I checked.

That error only happens when code is called in the thread `run()` method. And the same code works fine when `pthreads` functionality is not involved (e.g. an object is created in the main context).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of pthreads are you using ??

Comment: Hi, I was secretly hoping you'd come across this question. It's php_pthreads-0.1.0-5.4-ts-vc9-x86 running on PHP 5.4.25 on Windows. The strange this is that it doesn't happen in oversimplified cases, e.g. when I run code like I quoted in the query, but in my real project the issue exists. Autoloader seems to be working fine in the thread and it loads the same class, but still it sometimes work and sometimes doesn't...

Comment: Try to find the simplest code that exhibits the bug and report on github, I'll look at the weekend ...

Comment: Sorry for delay, it took time to pinpoint the problem, but here is the code exhibiting the issue and it indeed looks like a bug: http://j.mp/1frxKAb (download ZIP and run dummy.php, then edit dummy.php as its first comment line says and run again).

Please see the answer I just posted for the explanation. One more question - would you say the module is still ready for production as long as the error is avoided?

Comment: Not able to download code at that location ...

Comment: Sorry for that. But you can use the code from the answer, it's the same. Only create three separate files for every snippet and please let me know if that doesn't work for you. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for being annoying but I was wondering if you could replicate the issue using my code from the answer, or I need to github the issue?

Comment: This is a confirmed bug, I intend to look over the weekend at it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far it looks like an issue in php_pthreads which happens when a class instantiated in thread context has already been defined in parent context). It happens both in PHP 5.4 and 5.5 versions and the corresponding php_pthreads builds.

Here is an example:

**FoobarParent.php**

```
class FoobarParent {
    protected function _init() {
    }

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_init();
    }
}
```

**Foobar.php**

```
require_once('FoobarParent.php');

class Foobar extends FoobarParent {
    protected function _init() {
        print __METHOD__ . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

**dummy.php**

```
// uncomment the line below to exhibit an error in the thread context
//require_once('Foobar.php');

class T extends Thread {
    public function run() {
        // if the class used in thread context is only defined there, everything
        // is going to be fine
        require_once('Foobar.php');
        $foobar = new Foobar();
    }
}

$t = new T();
$t->start();
$t->join();

print "Finished" . PHP_EOL;
```

So if you still want to continue with multithreading you need to watch your autoloader closely to make sure thread context loads classes it needs for the first time.